# Embedding a CMS in an MVC Web App

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, content-management-system, embedded-resource

I'm working on a website for searching for businesses, then displaying a listing page. We've been toying with the idea of letting the clients manage their listing page using an external CMS. I'm not sure how often this is done, or if it's even best practice. Ideally, we want to be able to setup a listing on our website, then give the clients access to an external CRM when they can manage their listing page.

We then want to embed this custom page within our website, possibly using an iframe (which will come along with it's own set of complications). We'd like this integration to be as seamless as possible. I'd personally prefer it if we could directly inject the HTML into our own page and bypass an iframe all together, but I don't know of any CMS hosting services that provide the interface for such a thing.

We've experimented a little with Squarespace, and we can get a fairly clean version of someone's page which would be well suited for an iframe.

I'm wondering if anyone else has looked and integrating an external hosting CMS into a website (in this case, we're using ASP.NET MVC). We'd also want to automate the creation of accounts on this external CMS, so when a user signed up we could just point them to the website with some login details.

I have no idea if anyone offers a service like this, but any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

We could host a service ourself too, but the aim is to have an external system that clients can use to manage their pages.

Cheers,

James

Comment: Would be interesting to know what you ended up with?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use virtually any blogging service (wordpress comes to mind) as long as you had a totally clean template that would drop right into an IFRAME.

Comment: he explicitly states that he does not want to use iframes